# How to style links via textile?

Tags: css, textile

Is it possible to apply style attribute or class to link in textile? I've tried  to find a reference, but found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"{color:red}This is a testlink":http://www.google.com
```

or

```
"(myclass)This is a testlink":http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Hm, the answer is old, things must have changed, because today when I enter `"(myclass)This is a testlink":http://www.google.com` on [http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/index.php](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/index.php) I get **`<a href="http://www.google.com">(myclass)This is a testlink</a>`** and not the expected `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="myclass">This is a testlink</a>`. So how does this work for you, @avsej?